# GCP GroundingSource() returns groundingCancelled

Tags: google-cloud-platform

##### Environment details

- OS type and version: fedora, 7.9
- Python version: 3.11.0
- pip version: 23.3.1
- `google-cloud-aiplatform` version: 1.45.0

##### Steps to reproduce

I am trying to run the grounding score API from GCP, where I am passing the context as a string to the API. But, I am getting `groundingCancelled` in the output.

##### Code example

Here is the full code to reproduce the result:

```
from typing import Optional

import vertexai
from vertexai.language_models import (
    GroundingSource,
    TextGenerationModel,
    TextGenerationResponse,
)


def grounding(
        project_id: str,
        location: str = "",
        data_store_location: Optional[str] = None,
        data_store_id: Optional[str] = None,
        source: str = None) -> TextGenerationResponse:
    """Grounding example with a Large Language Model"""

    vertexai.init(project=project_id, location=location)

    # TODO developer - override these parameters as needed:
    parameters = {
        "temperature": 0.7,  # Temperature controls the degree of randomness in token selection.
        "max_output_tokens": 256,  # Token limit determines the maximum amount of text output.
        "top_p": 0.8,  # Tokens are selected from most probable to least until the sum of their probabilities equals the top_p value.
        "top_k": 40,  # A top_k of 1 means the selected token is the most probable among all tokens.
    }

    model = TextGenerationModel.from_pretrained("text-bison@002")
    # source = None
    if source is not None:
        grounding_source = GroundingSource.InlineContext(source)
    elif data_store_id and data_store_location:
        # Use Vertex AI Search data store
        grounding_source = GroundingSource.VertexAISearch(
            data_store_id=data_store_id, location=data_store_location
        )
    else:
        # Use Google Search for grounding (Private Preview)
        grounding_source = GroundingSource.WebSearch()

    response = model.predict(
        "What are the price, available colors, and storage size options of a Pixel Tablet?",
        grounding_source=grounding_source,
        **parameters,
    )
    print(f"Response from Model: {response.text}")
    print(f"Grounding Metadata: {response.grounding_metadata}")
    return response


source = "The Pixel Tablet, offered by Google, comes in three elegant colors: Porcelain, Hazel, and Rose. Let’s delve into the details: Price: The base model with 128GB of storage is priced at $499. If you need more storage, there’s a version with 256GB of storage available for $59912. Colors: Choose from the following stylish colors: Porcelain: A fresh and clean hue that’s new to Google’s tablet lineup. Hazel: A warm and inviting color option. Rose: A sophisticated choice for those who appreciate elegance3. Storage Size Options: The Pixel Tablet offers two storage variants: 128GB UFS 3.1 storage 256GB UFS 3.1 storage42. In addition to its sleek design, the Pixel Tablet boasts impressive specs, including an expansive 10.95-inch LCD display with a resolution of 2560x1600 pixels, 8GB LPDDR5 RAM, and the powerful Google Tensor G2 processor. Its battery life allows for up to 12 hours of video streaming, and it charges via the included Charging Speaker Dock or a separate USB-C® charger"

response = grounding(project_id="myprojecy", source=source)
```

In the response, I get:

```
MultiCandidateTextGenerationResponse(text=' Price: The base model with 128GB of storage is priced at $499. If you need more storage, there’s a version with 256GB of storage available for $599.\n\nColors: Choose from the following stylish colors:\n\nPorcelain: A fresh and clean hue that’s new to Google’s tablet lineup.\nHazel: A warm and inviting color option.\nRose: A sophisticated choice for those who appreciate elegance.\n\nStorage Size Options: The Pixel Tablet offers two storage variants:\n\n128GB UFS 3.1 storage\n256GB UFS 3.1 storage', _prediction_response=Prediction(predictions=[{'groundingMetadata': {'groundingCancelled': False, 'searchQueries': ['What are the price, available colors, and storage size options of a Pixel Tablet?']}, 'content': ' Price: The base model with 128GB of storage is priced at $499. If you need more storage, there’s a version with 256GB of storage available for $599.\n\nColors: Choose from the following stylish colors:\n\nPorcelain: A fresh and clean hue that’s new to Google’s tablet lineup.\nHazel: A warm and inviting color option.\nRose: A sophisticated choice for those who appreciate elegance.\n\nStorage Size Options: The Pixel Tablet offers two storage variants:\n\n128GB UFS 3.1 storage\n256GB UFS 3.1 storage', 'citationMetadata': {'citations': []}, 'safetyAttributes': {'blocked': False, 'safetyRatings': [{'probabilityScore': 0.0, 'severityScore': 0.1, 'severity': 'NEGLIGIBLE', 'category': 'Dangerous Content'}, {'probabilityScore': 0.1, 'severityScore': 0.0, 'severity': 'NEGLIGIBLE', 'category': 'Harassment'}, {'probabilityScore': 0.0, 'severityScore': 0.2, 'severity': 'NEGLIGIBLE', 'category': 'Hate Speech'}, {'probabilityScore': 0.1, 'severityScore': 0.1, 'severity': 'NEGLIGIBLE', 'category': 'Sexually Explicit'}], 'scores': [0.1, 0.1], 'categories': ['Insult', 'Sexual']}}], deployed_model_id='', metadata={'tokenMetadata': {'outputTokenCount': {'totalTokens': 136.0, 'totalBillableCharacters': 407.0}, 'inputTokenCount': {'totalTokens': 17.0, 'totalBillableCharacters': 68.0}}}, model_version_id='', model_resource_name='', explanations=None), is_blocked=False, errors=(), safety_attributes={'Insult': 0.1, 'Sexual': 0.1}, grounding_metadata=GroundingMetadata(citations=[], search_queries=['What are the price, available colors, and storage size options of a Pixel Tablet?']), candidates=[ Price: The base model with 128GB of storage is priced at $499. If you need more storage, there’s a version with 256GB of storage available for $599.

Colors: Choose from the following stylish colors:

Porcelain: A fresh and clean hue that’s new to Google’s tablet lineup.
Hazel: A warm and inviting color option.
Rose: A sophisticated choice for those who appreciate elegance.

Storage Size Options: The Pixel Tablet offers two storage variants:

128GB UFS 3.1 storage
256GB UFS 3.1 storage])
```

in which there is no information about grounding score.
I checked the backend, and I found the below version of the raw response in

```
predict, client.py:844
predict, models.py:1580
predict, _language_models.py:1343
```

which is called in `model.predict("What are the price, available colors, and storage size options of a Pixel Tablet?", grounding_source=grounding_source, **parameters)`.

In `predict, client.py:844`, which gets the response through send-request (`response = rpc(request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata,)`), the content of `response` is:

```
[struct_value {
  fields {
    key: "safetyAttributes"
    value {
      struct_value {
        fields {
          key: "scores"
          value {
            list_value {
              values {
                number_value: 0.1
              }
              values {
                number_value: 0.1
              }
            }
          }
        }
        fields {
          key: "safetyRatings"
          value {
            list_value {
              values {
                struct_value {
                  fields {
                    key: "severity"
                    value {
                      string_value: "NEGLIGIBLE"
                    }
                  }
                  fields {
                    key: "severityScore"
                    value {
                      number_value: 0.1
                    }
                  }
                  fields {
                    key: "probabilityScore"
                    value {
                      number_value: 0
                    }
                  }
                  fields {
                    key: "category"
                    value {
                      string_value: "Dangerous Content"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
              values {
                struct_value {
                  fields {
                    key: "severity"
                    value {
                      string_value: "NEGLIGIBLE"
                    }
                  }
                  fields {
                    key: "severityScore"
                    value {
                      number_value: 0
                    }
                  }
                  fields {
                    key: "probabilityScore"
                    value {
                      number_value: 0.1
                    }
                  }
                  fields {
                    key: "category"
                    value {
                      string_value: "Harassment"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
              values {
                struct_value {
                  fields {
                    key: "severity"
                    value {
                      string_value: "NEGLIGIBLE"
                    }
                  }
                  fields {
                    key: "severityScore"
                    value {
                      number_value: 0.2
                    }
                  }
                  fields {
                    key: "probabilityScore"
                    value {
                      number_value: 0
                    }
                  }
                  fields {
                    key: "category"
                    value {
                      string_value: "Hate Speech"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
              values {
                struct_value {
                  fields {
                    key: "severity"
                    value {
                      string_value: "NEGLIGIBLE"
                    }
                  }
                  fields {
                    key: "severityScore"
                    value {
                      number_value: 0.1
                    }
                  }
                  fields {
                    key: "probabilityScore"
                    value {
                      number_value: 0.1
                    }
                  }
                  fields {
                    key: "category"
                    value {
                      string_value: "Sexually Explicit"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        fields {
          key: "categories"
          value {
            list_value {
              values {
                string_value: "Insult"
              }
              values {
                string_value: "Sexual"
              }
            }
          }
        }
        fields {
          key: "blocked"
          value {
            bool_value: false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  fields {
    key: "groundingMetadata"
    value {
      struct_value {
        fields {
          key: "searchQueries"
          value {
            list_value {
              values {
                string_value: "What are the price, available colors, and storage size options of a Pixel Tablet?"
              }
            }
          }
        }
        fields {
          key: "groundingCancelled"
          value {
            bool_value: false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  fields {
    key: "content"
    value {
      string_value: " Price: The base model with 128GB of storage is priced at $499. If you need more storage, there’s a version with 256GB of storage available for $599.\n\nColors: Choose from the following stylish colors:\n\nPorcelain: A fresh and clean hue that’s new to Google’s tablet lineup.\nHazel: A warm and inviting color option.\nRose: A sophisticated choice for those who appreciate elegance.\n\nStorage Size Options: The Pixel Tablet offers two storage variants:\n\n128GB UFS 3.1 storage\n256GB UFS 3.1 storage"
    }
  }
  fields {
    key: "citationMetadata"
    value {
      struct_value {
        fields {
          key: "citations"
          value {
            list_value {
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
]
```

which apparently does not return the grounding score with `groundingCancelled` output. The help document (https://cloud.google.com/generative-ai-app-builder/docs/check-grounding?hl=en) suggests that the output should be in `[0,1]`.